# I'm trying to install microsft visual studio for building libpng library

Tags: zlib, libpng

- I have downloaded the Microsoft visual studio 2019, additionally i
  have selected desktop applications package as part of the download.
- I'm following a you-tube video for building the libraries,
  "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GsgSnSG0O0U". But things don't go as
  per the instructions in the video. I can't find the bin folder in the
  VC directory. And how do i build the libpng and zlib in visual
  studio.
- My project is about reading a PNG file, creating a PNG file, and in
  the final convert a BMP file to a PNG file. I will be using the code
  in an embedded application, where the image is captured from a camera
  and displayed onto the device. So can someone please help me on this.
  Any good documents.

Answer (score 0):

I am using the path like C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.24.28314\bin\Hostx86\x86\ instead and then run the bld_ml32.bat in the masmx86 folder.

Or change all to x64 for x64 cases.

Answer (score 0):

You might also use the nuget package manager to download and install the native package for libpng.